# Using DateDiff with GetDate() in tsql

Tags: t-sql, casting, datediff, getdate

I am trying to use GetDate inside a DateDiff along with a case statement.  If field one is null I would like to use the current date.  This is the code I am working with:

```
DateDiff(DAY, (Select Min(case when (demand_labor.arrive_dt is null)
      then GETDATE()
      else (demand_labor.arrive_dt)
      end)
      From demand Inner Join demand_labor On demand.demand_id =
      demand_labor.demand_id
      Where (order_line.order_id = demand.order_id)),
      c_service_call_env.resolve_date) As A2R2,
```

For one reason or another though when it is null it is not setting the date, the field stays null.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
ISNULL ( demand_labor.arrive_dt , GETDATE() )
```

[ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

DateDiff is supposed to have 3 components
Not sure what you are trying to do there

```
DateDiff(DAY, ISNULL ( demand_labor.arrive_dt , GETDATE() ), open_dt)
```

Comment: I am trying to do a dateDiff with the .arrive_dt and open_dt.  That being said though if the .arrive_dt is null I would like to check the dateDiff between the current date and the open_dt.   There also could be more then one .arrive_dt that is why I am selecting the min.

Comment: Then open_dt need to be in there some where and for a min you would need a group by.  Even if you don't know how to do then at least describe what you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

> I am trying to do a dateDiff with the .arrive_dt and open_dt. That
>   being said though if the .arrive_dt is null I would like to check the
>   dateDiff between the current date and the open_dt. There also could be
>   more then one .arrive_dt that is why I am selecting the min

a case statement should work

```
case when .arrive_dt is null then datediff(day, getdate(), Open_dt )
 else datediff(day, min(.arrive_dt), open_dt) end 
group by *as needed*
```

switch the order within the datediffs as needed

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b6c5/1/0

Comment: You can't mix an aggregate (min) with a non aggregate in a case statement. even this would fail datediff(day, min(.arrive_dt), open_dt)

Comment: @Blam  did you even try it?

Comment: trying to get sqlfiddle to help @Blam out

Comment: There is no group by in the posted question nor your posted answer.  And since the question is not clear not sure it answers the actual problem.  LookslikeAlittleLateToMe

Comment: im pretty sure it answered it his question, now if the Op wanted to get more specific then i can get more specific with the answer. 

would a case when statement work by itself? seems like you have more common sense than most people but just wanted to be a prick about the situation. get over yourself, it is responses like yours that pushes people away. either help or stay away.

@Blam

Comment: How can it answer the question if it throws a syntax error?  Did you test it? Without a group by the syntax is not valid.

Comment: the error it would have thrown is that it isnt in a group by - which woul dhave been fixed right away. get off your high horse man, at least my answer would have helped him a lot more than what you posted....how is your answer even an answer?

Comment: and at least I can think outside of the box, read his question and see what he was trying to do. what did you do? oh thats right, you couldnt even fathom what he was trying to do. @Blam

Comment: But he has a min without a group by now.  He is getting that error now and did not figure it out from the error message.  So your assertion that he will fix group by based on inspection is clearly invalid.  Rather than guess see my comment - at least describe what you want to do.